# How do you call a function outside in php?

Tags: javascript, php

When I filled the list of email addresses in a message box and when I click on a submit button, how do you call the closepopup function from the javascript in php when I post the message using this code?

```
if (!empty($_POST['message'])) 
{
    $emails = explode("\n", $_POST['message']); // explode textarea on a line break into an array
    $email_str = implode(", ", $emails); // take each of the emails and implode together with the ,
}
```

When I try this

```
if (!empty($_POST['message'])) 
{
    $emails = explode("\n", $_POST['message']); // explode textarea on a line break into an array
    $email_str = implode(", ", $emails); // take each of the emails and implode together with the ,
    closePopUp();
}
```

It will give me an error: **Fatal error: Call to undefined function closePopUp() in /home/myusername/public_html/PHP/examples/send.php on line 6**

Here is the full code:

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_POST['message'])) 
    {
        $emails = explode("\n", $_POST['message']); // explode textarea on a line break into an array
        $email_str = implode(", ", $emails); // take each of the emails and implode together with the ,
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Send Email</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"  />
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="pr_send.php" method="POST">
    <table> 
        <!-- <tr>
            <td>From:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="from"></td>
        </tr> -->
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" name="to" value="" style="height:24px; width:24px; background:url('addressbook.png'); border:none;" onClick="Popup()"> To:</td> 
            <td><input type="text" name="to" value="<?php if (!empty($email_str)) { echo $email_str; } ?>" style="height:15px; width:650px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Subject:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="subject" style="height:15px; width:650px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Message:</td>
            <td><textarea name="message" cols="90" rows="20"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
               <input type="submit" name="send" value="" style="height:35px; width:100px; background:url('send.png'); border:none">
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    </form>
    </body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var popup = null;
function Popup() 
{
  window.open("add_address.php", "_blank", "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=100, left=500, width=400, height=400");
}
function closePopUp() 
{
  if (popup) 
  {
    popup.close();
  }
}

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: it is undefined, you're directly calling the javascript function inside your PHP script, it doesn't work that way, PHP is server side, javascript is client side

Comment: @Ghost yeah I know that but I want to close the window. How I can do that?

Comment: @TimCullen you close the window upon submission inside `add_address.php`

Comment: @Ghost oh ok so how do you use this `<input type="submit" name="send" value="Add Email" style="height:35px; width:100px">` to close the popup window?

Answer (score 0):

we can call javascript function in php code like this

```
 if (!empty($_POST['message'])) 
 {
   $emails = explode("\n", $_POST['message']); // explode textarea on a line break into an array
   $email_str = implode(", ", $emails); // take each of the emails and implode together with the ,

   echo '<script> closePopUp(); </script>'; //call javascript function
 }
```

Comment: Thank you but when I try it it doesn't work. How do you close the window and output the email addresses from a message (in add_address.php) to output it in text box in send.php?